# Code running on main thread even with subscribeOn specified

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm in the process of migrating an `AsyncTaskLoader` to RxJava, trying to understand all the details about the RxJava approach to concurrency. Simple things were running ok, however I'm struggling with the following code:

This is the top level method that gets executed:

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(mDataRepository
            .getStuff()
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .subscribeWith(...)
```

mDataRepository.getStuff() looks like this:

```
public Observable<StuffResult> getStuff() {
    return mDataManager
            .listStuff()
            .flatMap(stuff -> Observable.just(new StuffResult(stuff)))
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> new StuffResult(null));
```

And the final layer:

```
 public Observable<Stuff> listStuff() {
        Log.d(TAG, ".listStuff() - "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        String sql = <...>;
        return mBriteDatabase.createQuery(Stuff.TABLE_NAME, sql).mapToList(mStuffMapper);
 }
```

So with the code above, the `log` will print out `.listStuff() - main`, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. And I'm not really sure why. I was under impression that by setting `subscribeOn`, every event pulled from the chain will be processed on the thread specified in the subscribeOn method.

What I think is happening, is that the source-aka-final-layer code, before reaching `mBriteDatabase`, is not from the RxJava world and therefore is not an event until `createQuery` is called. So I probably need some sort of a wrapper? I've tried applying `.fromCallable`, however that's a wrapper for non Rx code, and my database layer returns an observable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Log.d` call happens

- immediately when `listStuff` gets called
- which is immediately after getStuff gets called
- which is the first thing happening in the top level code fragment you show us.

If you need to do it when the subscription happens, you need to be explicit:

```
public Observable<Stuff> listStuff() {
    String sql = <...>;
    return mBriteDatabase.createQuery(Stuff.TABLE_NAME, sql)
      .mapToList(mStuffMapper)
      .doOnsubscribe(() -> Log.d(TAG, ".listStuff() - "+Thread.currentThread().getName()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I got confused and overcomplicated something really simple.